# Показывать ссылку на историю вопроса

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Сейчас ссылка на историю вопроса показывается только тогда, когда в него вносились изменения. Соответственно, в случае закрытия и переоткрытия без изменений ссылка не отображается. Аналогично ссылка не отображается, если вопрос был удалён как спам - там вообще странно - говорится, что содержимое можно просмотреть в истории, а ссылки на эту самую историю нет.

Кроме того, по ссылке на историю вопроса можно просмотреть его текст в markdown, что может быть удобно для его растаскивания на цитаты (особенно тем, кто ещё не заработал привилегию инлайнового редактированая (а то и вообще редактирования).

Ну и наконец, из ссылки на ревизии изменением одного слова делается ссылка на временную шкалу, которая может быть интересна безотносительно того, изменялся ли вопрос.

В общем, предлагаю либо всегда отображать ссылку, либо сделать таковой время написания.

PS: Интересно, что несколько дней назад я видел такие ссылки у вопросов на Ask Ubuntu, но сейчас они не отображаются...

Comment: Растаскивать на цитаты можно и без истории. Достаточно нажать кнопку "править", она доступна почти всем и всегда (кроме участников ниже 2000 репутации на Мете).